# How to make Wiremock listen specific host?

Tags: java, wiremock

I'm new with Wiremock - tool for stubbing. I don't understand how to make wiremock listen a specific host.
I want to stub some requests to my back end. The back end is running on domain1:port1. How can I do this?

1. Can I run wiremock on the same domain with different port? domain1:port2 so it can intercept all requests to domain1:port1?
2. Can I start wiremock server anywhere else and perform some command to make it listen domain1:port1?
3. or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Typically a stub is a replacement for the actual system. This often means that in the system using the stub a reconfiguration is made to point from the target system to the stub.

If you have only 1 setting for the back-end hostname and want to stub some calls, but not all of them, then have a look at [WireMock Proxying](http://wiremock.org/docs/proxying/).